# Cannot colocate hash partitioned table in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm trying to run through the demo instructions for [row-level geo-partitioning](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/multi-region-deployments/row-level-geo-partitioning/). I've created the parent table and tablespaces, but am getting the following error when attempting to create a partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions_us
    PARTITION OF transactions
      (user_id, account_id, geo_partition, account_type,
      amount, txn_type, created_at,
      PRIMARY KEY (user_id HASH, account_id, geo_partition))
    FOR VALUES IN ('US') TABLESPACE us_tablespace;

ERROR:  Invalid argument: Invalid table definition: Error creating table transactions_us on the master: Cannot colocate hash partitioned table
```

Are these demo instructions still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Your database is colocated, so tables you create inside the database are colocated by default. For now, we disallow hash partitioned colocated tables, so you got an error.

You have two options:

1. make the tables range partitioned (specify ASC/DESC instead of HASH)
2. don't use a colocated database

To try Row Level Geo Partitoning, do not use colocated databases. If you want to use colocation + row level geo partitioning, then you would have to switch to Tablegroups wherein we have a  work-in-progress feature that you can track here: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/5823